# Error while transpiling typescript angular app using gulp

Tags: typescript, gulp, angular, gulp-typescript

I'm having an error while transpiling typescript to js on an app using angular/gulp.

```
src/app/app.component.ts(1,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/core'.
src/app/main.ts(5,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/platform/browser'.
```

But everything works: the compilation is ok, inclusion and systemjs are ok so the app starts without problems. But I would like to avoid having this errors !

Here is the gulpfile I use:

```
const TS_CONFIG = {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
};
gulp.task('build.js.dev', ['clean.dev'], function () {
    gulp.src(['./' + APP_DIR + '/**/*.ts'])
        .pipe(ts(TS_CONFIG))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./' + APP_DEST));
});
```

This error is probably typings related but I don't get how to setup it right here...

Thanks for help.

Note: I'm using jspm_packages but there is not so much changes than using npm.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest and easiest way to remove those errors is to supply the definitions as sources for typescript compilations.

Adapt your task to something like that:

```
gulp.task('build.js.dev', ['clean.dev'], function () {
    gulp.src([
             'node_modules/angular2/core.d.ts',
             'node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts',
             './' + APP_DIR + '/**/*.ts'
         ])
        .pipe(ts(TS_CONFIG))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./' + APP_DEST));
});
```

Comment: It's even worst ! https://gist.github.com/Nek-/ecd2d8080e649e9c7b74 I also tried with something like 'web/jspm_packages/**/*.d.ts' but same result.

Comment: Im not sure if this approach is working with jspm dependencies - i have been only working with npm - are you using systemjs as module system in the typescript compiler?

Comment: No, actually I prefere to compile using gulp and it's watcher for many reasons (that are also describe somewhere in the angularjs documentation). Jspm download the *exact* same package as npm (the folder is jspm_packages/npm/angular2/... !). So it should work but doesn't; and don't know why.

Comment: Yeah indepedently of which task runner you use you ts onfig must be correct. Ill check what is appropriate for jspm.

Comment: I added angular in npm dependencies, still do not use it... But it works ! I don't know how, and it's an ugly fix... So if anybody have a solution to this problem I'm open.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend instead of supplying all files manually actually use your tsconfig.json that already have all required data:

```
gulp.task('build.js.dev', function() 
{
    var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');

    var tsResult = tsProject.src()
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())   
        .pipe(ts(tsProject));  

    return tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest('./' + APP_DEST));
});
```

Sample tsconfig.json:

```
{ 
    "compilerOptions": { 
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "system",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "dist",
        "typings/browser.d.ts",
        "typings/browser"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I tried with this config: https://gist.github.com/Nek-/8f89221cf88c1ed29078 And the result is **exactly** the same.

Comment: What version of tsc you are using?

Comment: The last ( `^1.7.5` )

Comment: It should be something local to your environment. Try doing it from scratch with angular 5 min quickstart sample (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) and see if you will get the same problems.

Comment: It doesn't use gulp !

Comment: To solve your problem you should go step by step eliminating possible reasons. First - does 5min tutorial with npm works? if no - there is something with your tsc. If it does - try build it with gulp to see if it will still work - and this way you will find the reason of your problems.